# Why my function cannot draw by matlibplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I set a function like that:

```
def triangular(x, a, b, c):
    if x <= a:
        return 0
    if a < x <= b:
        return (x - a)/(b - a)
    if b < x <= c:
        return (c - x)/(c - b)
    if c < x:
        return 0
```

I want to draw the image of this function so I use:

```
x = range(-10, 10, 0.1)
y = triangular(x,1,2,3) 
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

However, it shows error:`'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`, why? need I correct my function or input?

I tried to change to

```
x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
y = triangular(x,1,2,3)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

it shows

```
 The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```py
x = range(-10, 10, 0.1)
y = triangular(x,1,2,3)
```

use

```py
import numpy as np
...
x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
y = [triangular(elem_x,1,2,3) for elem_x in x]
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply but it didn't work, I add more info in my question

Answer (score 1):

You can also use NumPy indexing and masking to approach this problem avoiding for loops. Below is how you can do it. The conditions I am writing inside the function `triangular` in the square brackets `[...]` are just the boundary conditions described in your problem. It is more intuitive in the way it is written

```
def triangular(x, a, b, c):
    x[x<=a] = 0
    x[(a<x) & (x<=b)] = (x[(a<x) & (x<=b)] - a)/(b - a)
    x[(b<x) & (x<=c)] = (c - x[(b<x) & (x<=c)])/(c - b)
    x[x>c] = 0
    return x


x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
y = triangular(x.copy(),1,2,3) 
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]